# How Linux Epoll Checks Ready Fd: Sync or Async?

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, synchronization, epoll

I am confused a bit. Does epoll require polling loops checking if fd is ready ?
Is it completely synchronous I/O operation that means wasting cpu cycles or not ?
Finally; is it possible to obtain completely asynchronous I/O method that notifies kernel if i/o is ready ?

Comment: What do you mean by synchronous and asynchronous specifically? The words can have several different meanings in programming.

Comment: actually require cpu cycle or not?

Comment: You seem a little confused. Both synchronous and asynchronous calls using select/epoll wait efficiently, (ie. block the calling thread),  when waiting for something.

Comment: Martin i try to understand if kernel checks io readiness asynchronously or polling?

Comment: The kernel does not check 'I/O readiness'.  An I/O completion, (or error:), is signaled by means of a hardware interrupt that causes driver code to run, and that can make your waiting thread ready/running, no matter how it was waiting, sycnhronous call, async wait with select/epoll, whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does epoll require polling loops checking if fd is ready ?

Yes. You call the `epoll_wait` function, and it waits until any FD is ready, and then tells you which FDs are ready.

> Is it completely synchronous I/O operation

Depends what you mean by "synchronous". `epoll_wait` will wait, unless you give it a timeout of 0 milliseconds.

> that means wasting cpu cycles or not ?

No it doesn't.

> Finally; is it possible to obtain completely asynchronous I/O method that notifies kernel if i/o is ready ?

You aren't trying to notify the kernel when I/O is ready, it already knows that. You're trying to get the kernel to notify your program when I/O is ready.

For "fully asynchronous notifications" [you can get the kernel to send you a SIGIO signal](http://davmac.org/davpage/linux/async-io.html#sigio) - signals are fully asynchronous notifications. But you don't actually want that because it is a headache to program without creating deadlocks. If you did use that, you'd probably end up converting your signals back to some sort of synchronous notifications.

Comment: immibis what do you mean with fully async notifications if epoll_wait not wasting any cpu cycle? i understand from you that epoll_wait is async right ?

Comment: @RedArrow I don't understand what you think async means.

Comment: i understand from async that "not polling"

Comment: @RedArrow ah..  hence the confusion:(

Comment: @RedArrow And what is polling? You have to poll with epoll but you don't have to busy-wait.

Comment: @immibis as far as i know non blocking calls used at  async i/o and blocking calls at sync i/o processing needs. that's i understand. but does epoll check given file descriptors as poll/select. i.e when we increase the number of file descriptors to the large numbers then what should we consider for cpu load to check those file descriptors. it is told that epoll is different from poll/select in this manner. But actually it seems to be still synchronous

Comment: @RedArrow The difference with epoll is you don't have to process every file descriptor every time you call it.

Comment: @immibis you are right and thank you for your effort to explain. in fact i am confused about some comparisons between windows iocp and linux epoll. someones explain about differences. what is your opinion about those comparisions which says unix io primitivies are synch based but iocp is async based.

Comment: @RedArrow Perhaps the main difference between IOCP and epoll is that on IOCP, you start an operation and then you get told later when it completes (i.e. the operation happens asynchronously) and in epoll (and Unix in general), you get told when you can do the operation, and then you do it and it completes immediately (i.e. synchonronously).